# react-native-firebase scheduleNotification

Tags: react-native-firebase

I am trying to schedule 7 different notification on a daily basis with the following code.

```
    const interval = 1440;

    for (let i = 0; i < 7; i++) {
            const notification = new firebase.notifications.Notification()
                  .setNotificationId(notifyId + i.toString())
                  .setTitle('Quote of the Day')
                  .setBody('today is a beautiful day')
                  .setData({
                    dailyQuote:'today is a beautiful day'
                  });

            const date = new Date();
            date.setMinutes(date.getMinutes() + (i * interval));

            const schedule = {
                fireDate: date.getTime(),
                repeatInterval: 'day',
            };

    firebase.notifications().scheduleNotification(notification, schedule);
    }
```

However, the notifications fire all at once at the same time even though fireDate is set exactly 1440 minutes (1 day) later.

Can anyone help? Thanks!

Comment: I am having the same problem. I set a notification for tomorrow at 11:30 AM but it also fires today at 11:30 AM

Answer (score 0):

Changing the repeatInterval to 'week' did the trick for me.

```
const schedule = {
        fireDate: date.getTime(),
        repeatInterval: 'week',
      };
```